Can we get Workspace Customer ID through API for non-SuperAdmin users?
There is a value called Customer ID in Google Workspace, which will be unique for every Workspace. You can find this value in Google Admin Console -> Account -> Account Settings -> Profile -> Customer ID.
When trying to get this value via API, we found three APIs which will return the Customer ID in response. Those APIs are

Get Users List
Get a User
Retrieves a Customer

But only when trying with SuperAdmin accounts, the Customer ID is given in response. While trying with non-SuperAdmin accounts, we didn't get the Customer ID in Users APIs and we are getting 403 "Not Authorized to access this resource/api" in response.
Our question is, How can we get the Customer ID with non-SuperAdmin accounts? Is there any API available (or) any extra parameter we need to give to get the ID in response?

Admin SDK
Admin SDK API is mainly available for admin users of your organization. The Google Admin SDK is designed for managing Google Workspace settings and user accounts, which involves sensitive data and administrative functions. Unfortunately, there is currently no alternative for what you are trying to accomplish
Consider alternative solutions that might suit your needs, e.g assigning admin roles or using delegated authorities.
References: Admin SDK: Directory API , Admin SDK API reference
